# Swift UnitTest Undefined symbol for multiplatform App

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

I try to create unit tests with xcode 13.4.1

I create a new projet, lets call it `MyApp` including unit tests

`File -> New -> Project -> Multiplatform -> App`

I create a simple class for exemple

```
class Manager {
    
    var customData: CustomData
    
    init(custom: CustomData) {
        customData = custom
    }
    
    func setName(value: String) {
        customData.name = value
    }
}
```

With a simple data structure

```
struct CustomData {
    var name: String
}
```

Then I create a XCTestCase

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyApp

class Tests_iOS: XCTestCase {
    
    var manager: Manager = Manager(custom: .init(name: "Hello"))
    
    func testManagerChangeNameChange() {
        XCTAssert(manager.customData.name == "Hello")
        manager.setName(value: "Bonjour")
        XCTAssert(manager.customData.name == "Bonjour")
    }
}
```

But then I have this issues:

```
Undefined symbol: nominal type descriptor for MyApp.Manager

Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for MyApp.Manager

Undefined symbol: MyApp.CustomData.init(name: Swift.String) -> MyApp.CustomData

Undefined symbol: MyApp.Manager.__allocating_init(custom: MyApp.CustomData) -> MyApp.Manager


Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "nominal type descriptor for MyApp.Manager", referenced from:
      _symbolic _____ 5MyApp7ManagerC in Tests_iOS.o
  "type metadata accessor for MyApp.Manager", referenced from:
      variable initialization expression of Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.manager : MyApp.Manager in Tests_iOS.o
      Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.init(invocation: __C.NSInvocation?) -> Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS in Tests_iOS.o
      Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.init(selector: ObjectiveC.Selector) -> Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS in Tests_iOS.o
      Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.init() -> Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS in Tests_iOS.o
  "MyApp.CustomData.init(name: Swift.String) -> MyApp.CustomData", referenced from:
      variable initialization expression of Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.manager : MyApp.Manager in Tests_iOS.o
      Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.init(invocation: __C.NSInvocation?) -> Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS in Tests_iOS.o
      Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.init(selector: ObjectiveC.Selector) -> Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS in Tests_iOS.o
      Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.init() -> Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS in Tests_iOS.o
  "MyApp.Manager.__allocating_init(custom: MyApp.CustomData) -> MyApp.Manager", referenced from:
      variable initialization expression of Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.manager : MyApp.Manager in Tests_iOS.o
      Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.init(invocation: __C.NSInvocation?) -> Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS in Tests_iOS.o
      Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.init(selector: ObjectiveC.Selector) -> Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS in Tests_iOS.o
      Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.init() -> Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS in Tests_iOS.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. I think you might need to tell us more about what you mean by "I create a new projet". I created a new iOS project with unit tests, put your code into reasonable places, and the tests compiled just fine.

Comment: In xcode: File -> New -> Project

Comment: Are you using the same XCode version? (13.4.1), I'm going to download an other version to compare

Comment: Yes, I am using 13.4.1 too. If you like I can send you "your" project, compiling just fine.

Comment: The point is that after you say File -> New -> Project, there are two big "decision" screens you have to pass thru before you get to save the project. You have a _major decision to make_ about what kind of project it is. Tell me what decision you made at that point.

Comment: You are totally right, It is for a multiplatform App, I've updated the question

Comment: I've then also updated my research and found the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As the app is for multiplatform I find an anwser here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665120

The defaults tests are UI, you need to add a unit test target, then create a new build scheme

Comment: Yes, you said these were unit tests and I just believed you. :)